# FieldSet readString method not reading leading spaces

Tags: java, string, spring, spring-batch

I am reading records from file and inserting into database.

I am using DB2 database.

The records is like:

```
   abc    pqr  abcd
```

So before abc there are several spaces as well at the start of the record.

I am reading the file using SpringBatch program and inside field set mapper I am printing the string read from the file:

```
System.out.println("*" + fieldSet.readString("FULL_RECORD") + "*");
```

However, the result I am getting is:

```
*abc    pqr  abcd*
```

Which means that the leading spaces are not getting preserved.

The linetokenizer in my config file is:

```
<beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
    <beans:property name="columns" value="1-241"/>
    <beans:property name="names" value="FULL_RECORD"/>
  </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

I am using default line mapper class and passing above tokenizer as its property.

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper
```

How to preserve the leading spaces before each record?

Comment: Maybe there is a \t between "abc" and "pqr" and not a space.

Comment: @IMAnis_tn: Issue is only when there are leading spaces at the start of the record. Spaces between abc and pqr are fine.

Comment: So try to use trim() to eliminate the leading spaces on the start and the end of the record of course if you can have your record as a string.

Comment: There is not real question in your text, but did I get you right: You want to PRESERVE the trailing spaces?

Comment: @Ralph: I want to preserve the leading spaces... The leading spaces are not getting preserved which is clear from the Sys Out output in my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the code

1. the readString methods of the DefaultFieldset use
2. String.trim()

just change

```
System.out.println("*" + fieldSet.readString("FULL_RECORD") + "*");
```

too

```
System.out.println("*" + fieldSet.readRawString("FULL_RECORD") + "*");
```

see [DefaultFieldSet.readRawString()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/DefaultFieldSet.html#readRawString%28java.lang.String%29)

> Read the String value from column with given 'name' including trailing
>   whitespace (don't trim).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Did the same. However, I can not answer my own question, so could not update..